Evaluate $\mathbb{E} \exp(-\alpha \sum_{i}|x_{i}|)$ where $\mathbf{x}$ is Gaussian
Let $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$ be multivariate normally distributed vector, with given means and covariances:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf x] = \mathbf u\in\mathbb{R}^{N},\quad
\mathbb{E}[(x_i-u_i)(x_j-u_j)] = C_{ij}
$$
Question: Given a real parameter $\alpha$, can we find a closed-form expression for the following expectation:
$$
\mathbb{E} \exp\left( -\alpha \sum_{i}|x_{i}| \right) \quad?
$$
For example, in the one-dimensional case ($N=1$), there is a closed-form formula:
$$
\mathbb{E} e^{-\alpha|x|} =
\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{1}{2} \alpha \left(\alpha \sigma^2-2 u\right)} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{u - \alpha\sigma ^2}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+e^{2\alpha u} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\alpha\sigma^2+u}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+1\right)
$$
where $x \sim \mathcal N(u,\sigma)$. Obviously, we can use this expression if $C_{ij}=\sigma_i^{2}\delta_{ij}$ is diagonal, in which case $\mathbb{E} \exp\left( -\alpha \sum_{i}|x_{i}| \right) = \prod_i \mathbb{E}\exp(-\alpha|x_{i}|)$.
So the question is whether a generalization exists for higher-dimensions with non-trivial correlations, or not.

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334212/normal-multivariate-orthant-probabilities.

Shortly after posting, I found other posts addressing closely related problems, e.g.: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334212/normal-multivariate-orthant-probabilities.
Those questions answer in the negative: There is no closed-form expression in general for this integral.
